# How can I search the database with the checkboxes selected in php?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How can I search the database with the checkboxes selected in php?

**Note** : I have 10 checkboxes

Example: (Beach,Gym) If there is, I want to write the code that will only print it once

My code is running but it shows the same data a few times I want it to show the data one time

```
     $durum=$_GET["name"];

     $words= explode(",", $durum);
     
     foreach($words as $de)
     {
         
     echo $de;
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM kafe where $de='var'";
          $result = $conn->query($sql);
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
         // output data of each row
             while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
             echo $row["firmad"];
             echo "~".$row["firmatel"];
             echo "~".$row["firmaemail"];
             
         }
        }
     }
```

Comment: You should be aware, this creates a major [sql injection attack vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: How else can I solve it?

Comment: Its not related to your question, but you need to sanitize that `$durum=$_GET["name"];`, or the `$de` var inside the loop. As it stands a malicious user could send any sql they want to your DB... including DROP statements etc if the connection has those permissions, or just dump all the data from your database

Comment: what is `$de='var'` meant to do exactly? You're aware that `$de` in that query is going to be the column name, right? Are you meaning to search multiple columns for the static value `var`?

Comment: I need this for my application
Can you suggest another solution?

Comment: Sure, we just need you to explain what you're really trying to get :)

Comment: @WesleySmith yes

Comment: Automation for cafes, sports and entertainment venues

Comment: We dont really understand what `How can I search the database with the checkboxes selected in php` means. We see that you're only pulling one value from the request `$_GET["name"];` then your query explodes that and uses it as columns, not values. This makes it very difficult to understand what you expect the queries to return

Comment: Dont tell us what the site does at a high level, tell us what you expect the query to return

Comment: Example; $de=(beach,cafe,gym),
$de takes multiple values,
var=true,
SELECT * FROM kafe where $de='var'

Comment: can you show  a sample of the results you're getting now?

Comment: In Turkey "var" ownership within the meaning of the word in the sense that it is

Comment: also, do you expect a kafe to be returned if *any* of the provided columns are `var`, or only if *all* the columns are equal to `var`?

Comment: The cafes are turning but reprinting the same name

Comment: example.php?name=beach,gym

Comment: Gotcha, answer that last question and we can help write something that'll return each kafe only once

Comment: @WesleySmith Thank you, Glad you understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is include all of your conditions in one query, then loop over those results:

#### NOTE You didnt answer my question

> do you expect a kafe to be returned if any of the provided columns are var, or only if all the columns are equal to var?

Im assuming you want a kafe to be returned if any of the provided columns are var so I've used an "OR" in my code below, if you actually want a kafe to be returned only if all the columns are equal to var,  then change that to "AND"

```
            $durum     = 'beach,gym';
            $words     = explode(",", $durum);
            $conditions = array_map(function($value) use ($conn) {
                return $conn->real_escape_string($value). " = 'var'"; // prevent sql injection!, though parameterized queries (PDO) would be better
            }, $words);
            
            $conditions = implode(' OR ', $conditions);
            
            echo $conditions;


            $sql = "SELECT * FROM kafe where $conditions";
            $result = $conn->query($sql);
            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                // output data of each row
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    echo $row["firmad"];
                    echo "~".$row["firmatel"];
                    echo "~".$row["firmaemail"];

                }
            }
```

Comment: Thanks. It is working now

Comment: Exactly like I want